# How to completely isolate Windows 10 on it's own boot-drive?

Tags: windows, ssd

**Some background:**

I recently acquired a relatively small (256Gb) m.2 nvme drive to add to my desktop. I've been running a 1Tb SSD since I built my desktop but it's starting to get full. Until this year I used Windows 10 exclusively, but now I'm dual-booting Linux too. My desktop is for my personal use only and won't have multiple users on it if that would cause any issue.

**The issue:**

Getting the m.2 drive inspired me to research how I could make a dedicated boot drive for whatever OS I was into at the time, but it hasn't been as straightforward as I'd imagined. Essentially, I'm trying to completely isolate Windows 10 and its essential functions from any applications I install or files I download. Ideally, downloading files or installing applications wouldn't increase the size of my C drive at all. I've been researching ways to do this and I've found lots of tutorials outlining how to move specific things (the Users folder or the Program Files folders for example), but I'm worried that the methods may not work at all, or cause the system to fail given that I'm modifying core features of the OS. I guessed that the next step would be to ask a question to see if anybody had any insight or had tried this kind of "total data separation" before as it doesn't sound too far-fetched.

**What I've tried so far:**

I tried using Sysprep in audit mode to move the "Users" folder, but after rebooting into OOBE Windows claimed it was unable to complete the installation and needed to restart the install, thus undoing my work. I know it's also possible to do this with an already installed system though I haven't tried that yet. I also tried using regedit to change the path of "Program Files" and "Program Files (x86)" to be on the D drive. Then I installed Chrome to see if it would work and while most of the files were present on the D drive, a "Google" folder containing some logs and things still appeared in the "Program Files (x86)" on the C drive. Just today I started looking into junctions and I'm beginning to think they might be the answer.

I don't know if Windows 10 will even function with this kind of modification and I'm fully aware that this could entail a lot of manual maintenance down the line with potential updates, but the organization will make me warm and fuzzy inside so I'm willing to put in the extra work. I'd just rather not have to manually create a folder on the D drive for every application I want to install just to avoid filling up the system drive. Thanks in advance to anyone willing to offer insight.

This is the first time I've used any of the various stack websites so I hope I'm in the right place

Answer (score -1):

Ok so I ended up exploring symlinks and junctions further and they turned out to be the solution to my issue. Essentially, I just copied the contents of "Users" "Program Files" and "Program Files (x86)" into directories of the same name on my SSD, leaving everything else on the M.2, then created junctions to link them.

To do this, I just followed [this](https://docs-windows.readthedocs.io/en/latest/move-users-to-another-drive.html) tutorial and applied the same methods to the other folders I wanted to move.

I installed Chrome and it worked like a charm, even the shortcut was automatically placed on my desktop just as intended. I did this on a fresh installation of Windows which I had yet to update but the links have survived the updates and remain functional. Also, all the programs I copied work the same as they did before so this method should work just the same if you intend to apply this to an existing system. You would just have to do a fresh installation, delete the contents of the folders on the new one, and replace them with links to your original drive.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).